# Typescript eslint showing errors but not files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have recently upgraded all my eslint package (typescript, react, eslint imports, etc) and I'm getting the errors but not the files where the errors are.

I'm not sure what I need to post to solve this as I've compared this with a different project which is working. The only thing I've not upgrade yet is webpack.

Here is my EsLintPlugin from the config

```
new ESLintPlugin({
    // Plugin options
    extensions: ["js", "jsx", "ts", "tsx"],
    formatter: require.resolve("react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter"),
    eslintPath: require.resolve("eslint"),
    context: paths.appSrc,
    cache: true,
    failOnWarning: !isEnvDevelopment,
    emitWarning: true,
    failOnError: !isEnvDevelopment,
    cacheLocation: path.resolve(
        paths.appNodeModules,
        ".cache/.eslintcache",
    ),
    // ESLint class options
    cwd: paths.appPath,
    resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
    baseConfig: {
        extends: [require.resolve("eslint-config-airbnb")],
        rules: {
            ...(!hasJsxRuntime && {
                "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "error",
            }),
        },
    },
}),
```

Here is what I mean with the errors showing but no files.
[image: Example of error not showing files]

Let me know if I need to post anything else.

Thanks for you help

Comment: What command are you running to generate those messages? Or are they in your text editor, and if so, which one?

Comment: This is part of my webpack config and I'm just running `yarn start`. Running it in the command line on windows.